# fancyhdr - how to disable auto section number and still show section name in header

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, fancyhdr

```
\documentclass[fleqn,12pt,a4paper]{article}
%\RequirePackage{Kaumudi_Package}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{document}
\section{section-1} 
\newpage
\section{section-2}
\end{document}
```

In the above MWE, section name is placed in the page header which is great. However it also places a number in front of each section. I want to disable the number in front of the section. I managed to do that with `\section*{}` but that takes it off of the header as well. 
How can I disable the number in front of section and also show the name of the section in the header

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to redefine `\sectionmark` (refer to the package documentation for details); for example, you could use the following:

```
\documentclass[fleqn,12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[R]{\leftmark}
\renewcommand\sectionmark[1]{\markboth{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{}}

\begin{document}
\section{section-1}
\newpage
\section{section-2}
\end{document}
```

After processing the above exampe code you'll get the warning

```
Package Fancyhdr Warning: \headheight is too small (12.0pt): 
 Make it at least 14.49998pt.
 We now make it that large for the rest of the document.
 This may cause the page layout to be inconsistent, however.
```

which indicates that the defined header is too big; you can then add to the preamble something like

```
 \renewcommand\headheight{14.5pt}
```

To remove the section numbering for the body of the document, you could use `\titleformat` from the `titlesec` package:

```
\documentclass[fleqn,12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{}{0em}{}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[R]{\leftmark}
\renewcommand\sectionmark[1]{\markboth{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{}}
\renewcommand\headheight{14.5pt}

\begin{document}
\section{section-1}
\newpage
\section{section-2}
\end{document}
```

Is is to be noticed that the above code only suppresses the section numbering in the actual titles, but the numbering will still appear in the ToC and in the lower level sectional units; if the section numbering must be removed from the ToC and from the lower level sectional units, the following lines need to be added to the preamble:

```
\renewcommand\thesection{}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\arabic{subsection}}
```

Comment: there is still a number in front of the section in the document, I wanted to remove that as well. but if I do that then it removes from the header as well. I want the auto of section out in both places, in the document and also in the header. Sorry if my question did not make it clear.

Comment: @Raama please see my updated answer.

Comment: awesome, you guys are great

Comment: `\renewcommand\headheight{14.5pt}` results with "! You can't use `the character 1' after \the."; `\setlength\headheight{14.5pt}` seems to work for me. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to switch to a newer and more powerfull class like scrartcl which already has suitable commands:

```
\documentclass[fleqn,12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\pagestyle{fancy} 
\begin{document} 
\addsec{section-1}  
\newpage 
\addsec{section-2} 
\end{document}
```